# How to create list using python and pandas, by reading row by row.?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i have a huge CSV file with multiple columns, want to create a list whenever day column match todays date it should read User Agent columns and create a set.

```
UserAgentsToday = {}
for row in df:
    print((df.Day == "05/21/2019"))
    if row.["Day"]=="05/21/2019":
        UserAgentsToday.add(row["User Agent"])
print(UserAgentToday)
```

TypeError: string indices must be integers

```
UserAgentsToday = {}
for row in df:

    if df["Day"]=="05/21/2019":
        UserAgentsToday.add(row["User Agent"])
print(UserAgentToday)
```

The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Try `df.iterrows()`

Comment: When iterating directly on a DataFrame, you iterate on column names, so `row` is not what you expect.

Comment: @Rakesh getting the following error,  Item wrong length 1 instead of 57761.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `df.loc` with `unique()`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Day": ["05/21/2019", "05/21/2019", "05/21/2019"], "User Agent": ["Hello", "World", "Hello"]})
print(df.loc[df["Day"] == "05/21/2019", "User Agent"].unique())
```

**Output:**

```
['Hello' 'World']
```